# On DSPACE how to generate Thumbnail for Video?

Tags: dspace, video-thumbnails

Is there a way to generate thumbnails automatically for videos uploaded?
Just for the thumbnails form direct accessed folder videos i tried to generate it using ffmpeg and it works but can't find a way to integrated into dspace.
Am on dspace 5.4 , CentOS . For pdf and image I am using `ImageMagic`.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would suggest is to write a specific Media Filter for creating these thumbnails from videos.

The system of Media Filters is the framework used in DSpace to create derivatives of uploaded bitstreams for different purposes. For example, there is a Media Filter for the creation of thumbnails for PDFS, for the creation of a .txt version of an uploaded text document for full text indexing etc.

The documentation about Media Filters can be found here:
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Mediafilters+for+Transforming+DSpace+Content

On this page, follow section 5, creating custom media filters.

As far as I know, nobody has yet created a media filter for creating thumbnails for videos.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I created the media filter already and i rebuild and install it. And now it works. But i done this on development  environment. My question now is, Is there any option that i can copy only some files into the production server without rebuilding it from source or any other means that i can export the video filter functionality which is in my dev' server into another installed dspace without rebuilding. Cause i don't have the source for the production.